# 404 - Browser is looking for the wrong URL

Tags: angular

I have changed the URL of my API and deployed my application after using `ng build --prod`.

This is what I have changed:

**Before:**

```js
public getCookie(key): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.post<string>('/api/login/has-cookie', key);
}
```

**After:**

```js
public getCookie(key): Observable<string> {
  return this.http.post<string>('/api/login/get-cookie-by-uid', key);
}
```

On localhost everything seems to work fine. But when visiting the website on the server, the browsers tells *404* on *https://example.com/api/login/has-cookie*.

It should not be *has-cookie*. It should be *get-cookie-by-uid*. I have searched all over my whole project and I couldn't find "has-cookie" anywhere. Also, I have deleted the cache of my browser but I still get the same 404 error.

Why is that and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you delete the dist directory and run the ng build once more to be sure.

Comment: Have you try to restart the server?

Comment: As a sidenote, there's an environments directory with dev and prod settings. Put your dev config in the environments.ts and your prod config in the environments.prod.ts file. Import just the environments.ts file in your service. The prod file will be used when you `ng build --prod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I had changed the name of my project. So after building the application, I had 2 subdirectories: `old-name` and `new-name`. The browser pointed to the wrong URL, because it was looking for files in the directory `old-name`.